# "before each" hook: codeceptjs error message

Tags: protractor, codeceptjs

im using codeceptjs using protractor helper, and i tried to wtite simple code
and to run this command"npm run codeceptjs"
and i faced this error "× "before each" hook: codeceptjs.before for "test something" in 285ms"
here is my code on this file "test_test.js"

```
Feature('My First Test');

Scenario('test something', ({ I }) => {
I.amOnPage('/');
I.see('GitHub');
});
```

here package.json

```
  {
"name": "codeceptjs-tests",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "codeceptjs": "codeceptjs run --steps",
    "codeceptjs:headless": "HEADLESS=true codeceptjs run --steps",
    "codeceptjs:ui": "codecept-ui --app",
    "codeceptjs:demo": "codeceptjs run --steps -c node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples",
    "codeceptjs:demo:headless": "HEADLESS=true codeceptjs run --steps -c 
  node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples",
    "codeceptjs:demo:ui": "codecept-ui --app  -c node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@codeceptjs/configure": "^0.8.0",
    "@codeceptjs/examples": "^1.2.1",
    "@codeceptjs/ui": "^0.4.6",
    "codeceptjs": "^3.0.0",
    "playwright": "^1.19.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.0"
}
```

}
here codecept.conf.js file

```
       const { setHeadlessWhen } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

   // turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
    // export HEADLESS=true && npx codeceptjs run
   setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

 exports.config = {
    tests: './*_test.js',
    output: './output',
    helpers: {
     Protractor: {
  url: 'http://www.github.com',
  driver: 'hosted',
  browser: 'chrome',
  rootElement: 'body',
  angular: false
   }
  },
  include: {
  I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
name: 'Task1',
 plugins: {
pauseOnFail: {},
retryFailedStep: {
  enabled: true
},
tryTo: {
  enabled: true
},
screenshotOnFail: {
  enabled: true
}
 }
      }
```

how could i fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to be related to the selenium server. You can see details on https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/2634

Please follow the steps on codecept website for project setup
https://codecept.io/angular/#setting-up-codeceptjs-with-protractor